# How can I override Bootstrap CSS of an <a> element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am writing a blog, and I decided to use Bootstrap so I won't have to deal with media queries. I noticed the `<a>` element is blue. I have another CSS file that is loaded after the Bootstrap, and it does nothing if I use `color: black;`. I tried a lot of solutions but none worked. Here's my code:

```css
/* Here's styles.css: */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Blog</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body class="container">
  <header>
    <h5>Blog</h5>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <!--blog.html is the same as this one which is home.html-->
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `!important` keyword to override the style.

```css
/* Here's styles.css: */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Blog</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body class="container">
  <header>
    <h5>Blog</h5>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <!--blog.html is the same as this one which is home.html-->
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: solving this simple problem with `!important` is not the best idea.

Comment: Agree with @SandeshSapkota using !important to fix this kind of issues only makes the code harder to read, to mantain and to work with. `!important` should be used as little as possible, just use a more specific rule in your CSS instead of using that "workaround"

Comment: Yes. You are right. This is probably not the best solution. The higher specificity of a CSS selector should be used to rectify this kind of issue.

Comment: Just an observation, you don't have to specify the `a:hover` selector to change the color.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the styling of bootstrap for `a` tag has more specificity than yours. So It can be solved with making styling for `a` more specific than bootstrap's.

Here is the working demo

```css
/* Here's styles.css: */

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Blog</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>

<body class="container">
  <header>
    <h5>Blog</h5>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <!--blog.html is the same as this one which is home.html-->
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the a element isn't working, you can also try using a class inside the element. for example,

```css
/* This is the css */

.rmvBlue{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!--This is the html --> 

<a href="#" class="rmvBlue">Home</a>
<a href="blog.html" class="rmvBlue">Blog</a>
```

This may work because the class created is inside the a element so it should override everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap sets the color of the `a` elements targeting them directly using the next rules:

```
a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

You are trying to override these rules setting the color in the `header` (a parent element), and you are expecting the `a` elements get this color inheriting it from the `header`, but this is wrong. Check [what the documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Directly_targeted_elements_vs._inherited_styles):

> *Styles for a directly targeted element will always take precedence over inherited styles, regardless of the specificity of the inherited rule.*

So, to achieve what you want, there are multiple possibilities:

- Set the color in a rule that targets the `a` elements (this will apply the change to all the `a` elements on the page, not only to those inside the `header`)
- Create a [more specific rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (what @SandeshSapkota recommended)
- Create a new rule and add it to your `a` elements (what @Vanni recommended).
- Use the prebuilt [Boostrap color rules](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#color) (what I recommend). `text-dark` will do the trick for you.

But you should not use `important!` for this (what @yinsweet recommended and you accepted). You should use it to override page-specific styles coming from external CSS libraries only when you have tried everything else. Read [what the documentation recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception):

> *When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly with it. Using `!important`, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.*

Answer (score 0):

When you use important, you crush all the style tags on the page. Using it is often not recommended, and in most cases not even true. Because from now on, all the a labels you give me will be black. Or after you've done that, you'll have to re-use important when you want to make the color of the A tag different elsewhere. Correct this is not a method. You're using Bootstrap. it's possible to solve your problem with color labels. It would be a more accurate way to do that.

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body class="container">

    <header>
        <h5>Blog</h5>
        <a href="#" class="text-dark text-decoration-none">Home</a>
        <a href="blog.html" class="text-dark text-decoration-none">Blog</a>
        <!--blog.html is the same as this one which is home.html-->
      </header>
      
</body>
```

or you can specify a more specific path and adjust the color. like:

```
header a {
 color: black;
}
```

These will be more accurate.